# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-animation

I am trying to build a small multiplayer dice game. For doing this i want to update my connected realtime database when clicking on a button with the randomly generated dice results. In addition to the results I made an animation for my three dices.

When clicking the button before the animation has started the function to update my database works nice. When I click the button after the animation started I always get the following error:

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:547)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:159)
        at com.example.trdfschockt.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)`

I tried setting every attribute to public, implemented Serializable in every Class and even checked the proguard-rules file.

here is the code snippet where the problem arises:

``
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

```
public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
public Button rollDices, stopRoll, startAgain;
public Integer value, diceRollCounter, firstDice, secondDice, thirdDice;
public ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3;
public TextView textView1;
public static int[] diceResults = new int[3];
public static schockDecision newDecision;
public static Dice[] dices = new Dice[3];
public Player player = new Player();
public DatabaseReference myRef;
public Animation anim1, anim2, anim3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rollDices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollDices);
    stopRoll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRoll);
    startAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAgain);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    for (int i = 0; i < dices.length; i++) {
        dices[i] = new Dice();
        dices[i].setShouldDiceBeRolled(true);
        dices[i].setNumber(0);
    }

    diceRollCounter = 0;

    startAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rollDices.setEnabled(true);
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Player");
            String id = myRef.push().getKey();
            player.setUserId("asc");
            player.setSchockResult(0);
            player.setAmountDeckel(0);
            player.setUserName("Hans22112");
            player.setAufdeckReihenfolge(0);
            player.setFirstDice(dices[0]);
            player.setSecondDice(dices[1]);
            player.setThirdDice(dices[2]);
            myRef.child(id).setValue(player);
        }

     }
    );

    stopRoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            endOfRound();
        }
     }
    );

    rollDices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            diceRollCounter += 1;

            anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
            anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
            anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
            final Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    value = randomDiceValue();
                    int res = getResources().getIdentifier("dice_" + value, "drawable", "com.example.trdfschockt");
                    //if (animation == anim1) {
                    if (animation == anim1) {
                        imageView1.setImageResource(res);
                        diceResults[0] = value;
                        dices[0].setNumber(value);
                    } else if (animation == anim2) {
                        imageView2.setImageResource(res);
                        diceResults[1] = value;
                        dices[1].setNumber(value);
                    } else if (animation == anim3) {
                        imageView3.setImageResource(res);
                        diceResults[2] = value;
                        dices[2].setNumber(value);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Android classes, such as `android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`, cannot be written to the database without you writing custom code for that.

Your code will need to extract the important values from the `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` and write to to Firebase. Then when you read from the database, you'll have to create a `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` out of those properties again.

Also see:

- [Firebase Android - Crash with "Found a conflicting setters with name: setGregorianChange" when .setValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917562/firebase-android-crash-with-found-a-conflicting-setters-with-name-setgregori/41918838#41918838) (where I gave a longer explanation)

Comment: I located the error: I was trying to insert an object of my dice into the database. I totally forgot, that I made the animation an attribute in the dice class itself. therefore your comment totally leads to the problem. thx!